# Adding node in circular list in Java with only head

Tags: java

I'm trying to add a node in a circular list in Java. The problem is that my list has only a head (without a tail). Here is my code:

```
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.EmptyStackException;

public class CircularList {
    private Node head = null;

    private class Node {
        public Node(String payload, Node prev, Node next) {
            super();
            this.payload = payload;
            this.prev = prev;
            this.next = next;
        }

        private Node prev;
        private Node next;
        String payload = "";
    }
    public void push(String payload) {
        Node n = new Node(payload, null, null);
        if (isEmpty()) {
            head = n;
            n.next = n;
        } else {
            n.prev = head;
            n.next = head;
        }
    }
```

Comment: From the sounds of it, you want to add a new object and have it be the new head of the list? Is that what you mean by push?

Answer (score 1):

Lets take some nodes.

```
< H - < A - < B -
```

This describes the connections of the nodes. A.next == H and A.prev == B.

H and B are special cases, where H is the head and B is the tail. Since the list is circular. Then H.next == B and B.prev == H.

When we push a node.

```
< N - < H - < A - < B -
```

Then we can see all of the assignments that need to change.

```
H = head;
B = H.next; // get the tail since you only have the head.
H.next = N;
N.prev = H;
N.next = B;
B.prev = N;
head = N;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. When the list is empty, that part works fine. But when the list is not empty, think through what needs to happen, which is **4 things**:

- The 'head's previous node needs to become the new node.
- The new node's 'next' needs to point at head.
- The new node's 'previous' needs to point at what *used to be* `head.prev`.
- What *used to be* `head.prev`'s `next` pointer needs to point at the new node.

You'll need some temp variables to take care of all of that.

Comment: Should the new node become the head? It seems like you've written this such that the new node becmes the second node.

Comment: OP's question is unclear. I would assume that `head` remains unchanged, and that the new node can be gotten to either by traversing forward (`.next.next.next.next....`) until you get there, or by going back 1 step (`head.prev` points at the new node). That should mirror the notion of 'add at the end'. If OP wants the added node to _be_ `head`, you still need to update 4 things, just update them slightly differently. This answer is meant to guide them there (primarily, clue in that 4 things need updating and that temp variables may be required).